# Статический контент и CDN

Tags: static, cdn, static-content

Всем привет!

Есть ли разница в доменной зоне (.com, .eu, .cz) для раздачи статического контента (стили, изображения и тп)?

Например: основной адрес проекта domain.eu, для статики лучше выбрать домен **cdn.domain.com** или можно оставить **cdn.domain.eu**?

Comment: Разница есть только если домены разного уровня. Если домены одного уровня, то не принципиально.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Т.е. есть смысл купить домен второго уровня и раздавать статику с него (Например: cdndomain.com)?
Какие плюсы даст такая схема?

Comment: По сравнению с чем?

Comment: В сравнении с доменом третьего уровня cdn.domain.eu.

Comment: Да не принципиально. Там разница незаметна. Что дешевле, то и берите)